# Output of returning the digit does not come as expected?

Tags: java, arrays

> Given an array of numbers as input, return the digit which occurs the maximum number of times in the input.

I don't know the size of the new array I am creating.I assumed the size is twice.To separate the digits I divided the number took it modulas and added to the new array.After that I found the maximum number in the new array.But I am not getting the output as Expected.

@Edit According to the Answers mentioned I edited the code.Now the problem occurs is that my array c values are not referenced.(I mean I separated them by their Digits but I am getting the same array of numbers when I am returning q

> Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong?

```
 public int frequentDigit(int[] numbers)
 {
   int q=0;
   int c[]=seperateDigits(numbers);
   int p=findMax(c);
   for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
   {
    if(p==i)
    {
        //b1=true;
        q=numbers[i];
       break;
    }
   } 

   return q;

 }      

 int[] seperateDigits(int[] numbers) 
 {     
  int count=0;

  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
  {
   int aNumber = numbers[i];
   if(aNumber==0)           //@Edit
   count++;
  else
  {
     while (aNumber > 0) 
    {
      int aDigit = aNumber % 10;
      System.out.println(aDigit);
       count++;


     aNumber = aNumber / 10;
    }
  }

 }
 int c[] = new int[count];

 for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
 {
  int aNumber = numbers[i];
  if(aNumber==0)           //@Edit
     c[i]=aNumber;
  else
  {
     while (aNumber > 0) 
    {
      int aDigit = aNumber % 10;
      //System.out.println(aDigit);
       //count++;
      c[i]=aDigit;             //@Edit
     //System.out.println(c[i]);  //@Edit

     aNumber = aNumber / 10;
    }
  }

 }
 return c;
}

    int findMax(int c[]) 
    {
        int max = c[0];
        int max_i = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < c.length; i++)
        {
            if (c[i] > max) 
            {
                max = c[i];
                max_i = i;
            }
        }
        return max_i;
    }
```

Output

```
       Parameters          |  Actual Output  |  Expected Output
---------------------------|-----------------|-----------------
{24,27,30,31,34,37,40,42}  |     40          |        3
```

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. Can you provide example ?

Comment: Nitpick: `for(;numbers[i]>0;)` should be `while(numbers[i]>0)`

Comment: Why do you believe you need an array that is 2 times the length of the input array? There are **10** digits in our standard numbering system, so you need 10 counters, regardless of number of input values, or their lengths, e.g. what if input was `12345, 54321, 24, 159, 2468, 98765, 0, 1020304050`? (Remember to count the `0` value as having one `0` digit).

Comment: *FYI:* For your example (`24,27,30,31,34,37,40,42`), the answer could also be `4`, because both `3` and `4` occurs four times.

Comment: Code won't compile. Multiple returns in one function at the top.

Comment: @Andreas You are right.How to split the elements.

Comment: @Andreas Also, I was just bypassing one test case :P.Sorry,I couldn't think of a general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things that I see...

1) Your `frequentDigit` method should return `int`, not `int[]`.

2) You need to use an array of length 10 as @Andreas mentions in comments.

3) Your `findMax` method is returning the number of times the most frequent digit occurs, not the digit itself. To capture the digit, you'll need to track both max and the i value that corresponds to it. You don't need to check the length of `c`, the `for` loop does that for you.

```
int findMax(int c[]) {
    int max = c[0];
    int max_i = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i] > max) {
            max = c[i];
            max_i = i;
        }
    }
    return max_i;
}
```

4) Your `for` loop in `seperateDigits` (aside: "separate", not "seperate") is doing some mysterious things which are well-motivated but incorrect.

```
int c[] = new int[10];
//System.out.println(c.length);
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    int aNumber = numbers[i];
    if (aNumber == 0)
        c[0]++;
    else {
        while (aNumber > 0) {
            int aDigit = aNumber % 10;
            System.out.println(aDigit);

            c[aDigit]++;
            System.out.println(c[aDigit]);

            aNumber = aNumber / 10;
        }
    }
}
```

### The Whole Enchilada

```
package xyz;

public class DigitCounter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DigitCounter me = new DigitCounter();
        System.out.println(me.frequentDigit(24, 27, 30, 31, 34, 37, 40, 42));
        System.out.println(me.frequentDigit(12345, 54321, 24, 159, 2468, 98765,
                0, 1020304050));
        System.out.println(me.frequentDigit(123, -654, 879));
        System.out.println(me.frequentDigit(0));
    }

    public int frequentDigit(int... numbers) {
        int c[] = separateDigits(numbers);
        int p = findMax(c);
        return p;
    }

    int[] separateDigits(int[] numbers) {
        int c[] = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            int aNumber = numbers[i];
            if (aNumber == 0)
                c[0]++;
            else {
                while (aNumber > 0) {
                    int aDigit = aNumber % 10;
                    c[aDigit]++;
                    aNumber = aNumber / 10;
                }
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    int findMax(int c[]) {
        int max = c[0];
        int max_i = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (c[i] > max) {
                max = c[i];
                max_i = i;
            }
        }
        return max_i;
    }
}
```

Comment: If a number is `0`, this code will not increment the counter for the zero digit.

Comment: @Andreas for number 0 we can do like.I have edited the code.

Comment: @Erick G. Hagstrom Please check if my corrections were right?

Comment: @Andreas Please check if my corrections were right and any more corrections required

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom What changes you made now ?I have changed the code according to what you said but still it shows incorrect output.

Comment: I added the whole enchilada and incorporated the test cases that @Andreas used. All should be clear now.

Comment: Oh, and I got rid of the interior `println`s.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a combined version. It can handle zero values (counts as a single `0` digit) and negative values (sign is ignored). An empty array returns `-1`, and a null array throws `NullPointerException`.

```
private static int findMostFrequentDigit(int ... input) {
    int[] digitCount = new int[10];
    for (int value : input)
        do {
            digitCount[Math.abs(value % 10)]++;
        } while ((value /= 10) != 0);
    int maxCount = 0, maxDigit = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (digitCount[i] > maxCount) { // or >= to find the last max-digit
            maxCount = digitCount[i];
            maxDigit = i;
        }
//  printDebug(input, digitCount, maxCount);
    return maxDigit;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(findMostFrequentDigit(24,27,30,31,34,37,40,42));
System.out.println(findMostFrequentDigit(12345, 54321, 24, 159, 2468, 98765, 0, 1020304050));
System.out.println(findMostFrequentDigit(123, -654, 879));
System.out.println(findMostFrequentDigit(0));
```

*Output*

```
3
0
1
0
```

---

For nice debug output, use this method and uncomment the `printDebug()` line above:

```
private static void printDebug(int[] input, int[] digitCount, int maxCount) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));
    String format = "%" + (Integer.toString(maxCount).length() + 1) + "d";
    System.out.print("  Digit:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.printf(format, i);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("  Count:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.printf(format, digitCount[i]);
    System.out.println();
    format = "%" + (Integer.toString(maxCount).length() + 1) + "s";
    System.out.print("  Max:  ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.printf(format, digitCount[i] == maxCount ? "^" : "");
    System.out.println();
}
```

*Output*

```
[24, 27, 30, 31, 34, 37, 40, 42]
  Digit: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  Count: 2 1 3 4 4 0 0 2 0 0
  Max:         ^ ^          
[12345, 54321, 24, 159, 2468, 98765, 0, 1020304050]
  Digit: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  Count: 6 4 5 3 5 5 2 1 2 2
  Max:   ^                  
[123, -654, 879]
  Digit: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  Count: 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  Max:     ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
[0]
  Digit: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  Count: 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  Max:   ^
```

Comment: You have a nice approach.+1 for that.But I wanted what I am doing wrong in my code apart from the array size you mentioned.