# Output of finding maxFreq of digit in an array of numbers does not come as expected

Tags: java, arrays, digits

> Given an array of numbers as input, return the digit which occurs the maximum number of times in the input.

**MyApproach**

I first separated each digit of each member of the array. Then, I counted the frequency of each digit and then I found the max number of times the digit occurs and noted its position. And when I searched for the position in the array of separation of digits I found the digit that occurs maximum number of times.

This is what I tried to do with the following code:

```
 int[] seperateDigits(int[] numbers)
 {

  int c[]=new int[numbers.length*2];
  for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
   {
     for(int k=0;numbers[i]>0;i++)
     {

           int q=numbers[i]%10;   //used this logic for separation of digits
           System.out.println(numbers[i]);

           c[k]=q;
           System.out.println(c[k]);
            k++;
           numbers[i]=numbers[i]/10;

     }
    }
       return c;
  }

    int countMaxFreq(int c[])
    {
        int t[]=new int[c.length];
        int count=1;
       if(c.length<2)
       return count;
       else
       {

           //used the logic for finding maximum frequency of each digit.
           int m=0;
          for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
          {
              for(int j=i+1;j<c.length;j++)
              {
                  if(c[j]==c[i])
                 {
                    count++;

                 }

              }  
               t[m++]=count;

          }
       }  
       if(c.length<2)
       return c[0];
       else
       {

        int max=t[0];
        int max_index=0;
        for(int i=1;i<t.length;i++)
         {
           if(t[i]>=max)    //used the logic for finding frequency.
           {
               max_index=i;
           }
         }
         for(int l=0;l<c.length;l++)
         {                               //Return the position of the frequent element.
             if(l==max_index)
             {
               break;
             }
         }
         return max_index;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are trying to return the count as well as the number which has occurred max,times in the same function i.e.,CountMexFreq , they should be two separate function or change some logic

Comment: Why is the `i` for-loop and the `k` for-loop both doing `i++`? What is the logic of the `c` array being 2 times the size of `numbers`? If you call `seperateDigits(new int[] { 1234, 5, 9876, 0 })`, I would have expected the returned value to be `[1,2,3,4,5,9,8,7,6,0]`, but running it returns `[4,5,6,0,0,0,0,0]`. Oh, and it spelled "sep**a**rate".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output of returning the digit does not come as expected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094296/output-of-returning-the-digit-does-not-come-as-expected)  It even misspells `seperateDigits` the same way.

Comment: @ZeeMesi That's the slow way of doing it.

Comment: Please read "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)", especially the part about "Minimal" - "Divide and conquer". The first method (`seperateDigits`) is not working, and until that is fixed, the rest is superfluous. Ask one question only, which in this case would be: "Why isn't `seperateDigits()` working". It is not "Why isn't `countMaxFreq()` working", because the answer to that is simple: It's given garbage input.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry Sir.I was confused at that point of time.So,I asked the question again.The Ans was correct there I think I should delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the approach, to this algorithm:

- create a `int[] counts = new int[10]`, there are at most 10 digits
- for each number in the input

  - for each digit
  - increment the count of the digit
- find the max element, return its index, that's the digit you're looking for

For example:

```
if (numbers.length == 0) {
    throw new NoSuchElementException("no numbers, so 'most frequent' makes no sense");
}

int[] counts = new int[10];

for (int num : numbers) {
    if (num == 0) {
        ++counts[0];
    } else {
        num = Math.abs(num);
        while (num > 0) {
            int digit = num % 10;
            num /= 10;
            ++counts[digit];
        }
    }
}

return IntStream.range(0, counts.length)
    .reduce((i, j) -> counts[i] < counts[j] ? j : i)
    .getAsInt();
```

Note: when there are multiple digits with the same count, this implementation will return the smaller digit.

Answer (score 0):

Make your function return only the variable not its count

```
int countMaxFreq(int c[])
{
    int t[]=new int[c.length];
    int count=1;

       //removed the logic here
       //used the logic for finding maximum frequency of each digit.

   if(c.length<2)
   return c[0];
   else
   {
      int m=0;
      for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
      {
          for(int j=i+1;j<c.length;j++)
          {
              if(c[j]==c[i])
             {
                count++;

             }

          }  
           t[m++]=count;

      }

    int max=t[0];
    int max_index=0;
    for(int i=1;i<t.length;i++)
     {
       if(t[i]>=max)    //used the logic for finding frequency.
       {
           max_index=i;
       }
     }
     for(int l=0;l<c.length;l++)
     {                               //Return the position of the frequent element.
         if(l==max_index)
         {


           break;
         }
     }
     return max_index;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
public int countFreq(int[] c){
   int[] frequencyChart = new int[c.length]; //always give useful names for variables, it always helps.
   if(c.length < 2){
      return c[0];
   }
   else{
      for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){//loops through array
         for(int j = 0; j < c.length; j++){//nested loop that'll count frequencies.
            if(c[i] == c[j]){
               frequencyChart[i]++;
            }
         }
   }
   //this would have set up the array of frequencies, which corresponds with everything in c. Note: there will be duplicates of frequencies.
   int maxFreq = frequencyChart[0];
   int mostFreq = c[0];
   for(int a = 0; a < frequencyChart.length; a++){//now to find the highest frequency...
       if(frequencyChart[a] > maxFreq){
            maxFreq = frequencyChart[a];
            mostFreq = c[a];
       }
   }
   return mostFreq;
}
```

Hope that this helped!

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers to this question explain problem in the current implementation and offer solutions for it. I won't repeat them, but I would like to suggest a Java 8 style solution based on the streaming capabilities.

First, you'd need a way to stream the digits of a number. The easiest way to do that would probably be to extend [`Spliterators.AbstractIntSpliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.AbstractIntSpliterator.html) (note that this supplier returns the digits from the last digit to the first. Since we don't care about the order for this problem, it is sufficient):

```
public class ReverseDigitSupplier extends Spliterators.AbstractIntSpliterator {
    private int number;

    private ReverseDigitSupplier(int number) {
        super(Long.MAX_VALUE, 0);
        this.number = Math.abs(number);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(IntConsumer action) {
        int digit = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        action.accept(digit);

        return number != 0;
    }
}
```

Once you have such a capability, you could do the following (explanations inline):

```
Integer commonDigit = 
    Arrays.stream(numbers) // stream the array
          .flatMap(x -> StreamSupport.intStream
                        (new ReverseDigitSupplier(x), false)) // stream digits
          .boxed() // convert int to Integer
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy
                   (Function.identity(), 
                    Collectors.counting())) // Group to a cardinality map
          .entrySet() // Take the entrySet() of the map
          .stream() // stream it
          .reduce(BinaryOperator.maxBy
                  (Map.Entry.comparingByValue())) // find the max value
          .map(Map.Entry::getKey) // take the key
          .orElse(null); // and terminate the optional
```

Answer (score 0):

> Given an array of numbers as input, return the digit which occurs the maximum number of times in the input.

This will help you .Its easy and not using any build function.

```
public class MostFreqDigit {
static int[] testcase1 = {24,27,30,30,31,34,37,40,42,10,0};
  public static void main(String args[]){
  MostFreqDigit testInstance = new MostFreqDigit();
  int result = testInstance.frequentDigit(testcase1);
  System.out.println(result);
  }
  public int frequentDigit(int[] numbers){
  //write your code here
  int mostfreq=0;
  int y=0;
  char dig='\u0000';
  String str="";
  for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){

      str=str+numbers[i];

  }
  for(int j=0;j<str.length();j++){
      char ch=str.charAt(j);
      int c=exists(ch,str);
      if(c>mostfreq){
          mostfreq=c;
          dig=ch;
          y=ch-48;
      }
      else if(c==mostfreq){ 
          if(dig>ch){
              dig=ch;
              y=ch-48;
          }
          }
  }

  return y;
}
public int exists(char c,String s){
   int count=0;
   for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
       if(s.charAt(i)==c)
       count++;
   }
   return count;
}
}
```